# HtmlUnit encoding

Tags: java, htmlunit

Whenever I click on a button, I get the wrong encoding. How to fix it?

```
    package com.company;

    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.*;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
    import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;      
    import java.util.logging.Level;

    public class Parsing {
        public void connect() throws Exception {
            LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

            WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
            client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
            client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            String url = "https://auto.ru/cars/new/group/mercedes/e_klasse/20743577/20886691/?grouping_id=tech_param_id%3D20743577%2Ccomplectation_id%3D21225392&sort=fresh_relevance_1-desc&geo_radius=200";

            HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);
            HtmlElement clickContact = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("confirm-button");
            page = clickContact.click();
            client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

            System.out.println(page.asText());

        }
```

Output:

> ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚! Ð�Ð²Ñ‚Ð¾.Ñ€Ñƒ Ð›ÐµÐ³ÐºÐ¾Ð²Ñ‹Ðµ ÐœÐ¾Ñ‚Ð¾
>   ÐšÐ¾Ð¼Ð¼ÐµÑ€Ñ‡ÐµÑ�ÐºÐ¸Ðµ  ...

Comment: Most probably this page is obfuscated to protect itself against scraping.

Comment: Will have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url = "https://auto.ru/cars/new/group/mercedes/e_klasse/20743577/20886691/?grouping_id=tech_param_id%3D20743577%2Ccomplectation_id%3D21225392&sort=fresh_relevance_1-desc&geo_radius=200";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_60)) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

        HtmlElement clickContact = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("confirm-button");
        page = clickContact.click();
        System.out.println("still running " + webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60_000));
        System.out.println(" ---- ");

        // the page content got changed via javascript
        // we like to get see the new content
        page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
        System.out.println(page.asText());
    }
}
```

I do not get the whole content correct but major parts.